# splitting the bill algorithmically & fair, afterwards :)

Tags: python, algorithm, math, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to solve the following real-life problem you might have encountered yourselves:

You had dinner with some friends and you all agreed to split the bill evenly. Except that when the bill finally arrives, you find out not everyone has enough cash on them (if any, cheap bastards).

So, some of you pays more than others... Afterwards you come home and try to decide "who owes who what amount?".

This, I'm trying to solve algorithmically & fair :)

it seems so easy at first, but I'm getting stuck with rounding and what not, I feel like a total loser ;)

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

EDIT: Some python code to show my confusion

```
>>> amounts_paid = [100, 25, 30]
>>> total = sum(amounts_paid)
>>> correct_amount = total / float(len(amounts_paid))
>>> correct_amount
51.666666666666664
>>> diffs = [amnt-correct_amount for amnt in amounts_paid]
>>> diffs
[48.333333333333336, -26.666666666666664, -21.666666666666664]
>>> sum(diffs)
7.1054273576010019e-015
```

Theoratically, the sum of the differences should be zero, right?

for another example it works :)

```
>>> amounts_paid = [100, 50, 150]
>>> total = sum(amounts_paid)
>>> correct_amount = total / float(len(amounts_paid))
>>> correct_amount
100.0
>>> diffs = [amnt-correct_amount for amnt in amounts_paid]
>>> diffs
[0.0, -50.0, 50.0]
>>> sum(diffs)
0.0
```

Comment: The problem has two parts: 1) deciding how much should every person pay and 2) saying how much ever person owes money (or should receive, if he paid more than his share). Both seem pretty simple. Which part gives you a trouble?

Comment: hi, thanks, I think my problem lies with the fact that the amount is not always evenly dividable, so coming up with an algorithm that handles this elegantly seems to trip me up again & again.

Comment: "not always evenly dividable"?  In the US that means fractions of a cent.  Usually "noise" that's rounded UP to be sure the entire bill is covered.  How much a problem is this?  Really?

Comment: -1: Never. Do. Finance. With. `float`. Never.

Comment: I think it comes down to elegantly designing an algorithm for the task. When the numbers don't add up correctly in the end, how do you know it's the end? But then again, perhaps I'm confusing myself more than I need to at this moment.

Comment: "When the numbers don't add up correctly in the end, how do you know it's the end?"  You know it's the end because the math is trivial.  The `float` round-off is not part of the algorithm.  Your "error" is 10**-15.  You'd have to split billions of meals to even accumulate a $0.01 error.  Start now.  In several centuries, when you've accumulated a $0.01 error, you have something to talk about.  Until then, stop coding and start thinking.

Comment: I once tried to write a webapp that solved a superset of this problem and I gave up because of the complexity...

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+floating-point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to treat each person as a separate account.

You can easily determine (from the original bill) how much each person *should* pay. Set this as a negative amount for each person. Next, record the amount that each person *has paid* by adding the amount paid to their account. At this point, the people who have overpaid (lenders) will have positive balances, and the people who have underpaid (borrowers) will have negative balances.

There is no one right answer to which borrower owes money to each lender, except in the obvious case where there is only one lender. Amounts paid by a borrower can go to any of the lenders. Simply add the amount to the borrower's total, and subtract amounts from the lenders who receive the payment.

When all accounts hit zero, everyone has paid up.

**Edit** (in response to comments):

> I think my problem lies with the fact that the amount is not always evenly divisible, so coming up with an algorithm that handles this elegantly seems to trip me up again & again.

When dealing with dollars and cents, there is no 100% clean way to handle the rounding. Some people will pay one cent more than others. The only way to be fair is to assign the extra $0.01 at random (as required). This would be done only once, when the "amount owed" is being calculated by dividing up the bill. It sometimes helps to store monetary values as cents, not as dollars ($12.34 would be stored as 1234, for example). This lets you use integers instead of floats.

To distribute the extra cents, I would do the following:

```
total_cents = 100 * total;
base_amount = Floor(total_cents / num_people);
cents_short = total_cents - base_amount * num_people;
while (cents_short > 0)
{
    // add one cent to a random person
    cents_short--;
}
```

**Note:** the easiest way to assign the pennies "randomly" is to assign the first extra cent to the first person, the second to the second, etc. This only becomes a problem if you always enter the same people in the same order.

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I was going for, but if you see my code example which I added into the post, you'll see it will not always come down to zero, unless I'm going at it completely the wrong way.

Comment: The partial dollars get tricky. I've edited my answer to (hopefully) deal with that issue.

Comment: "there is no 100% clean way to handle the rounding".  Worse.  @gumuz has spent more time on the rounding than the fractions of a cent are worth.  It would have been cheaper for @gumuz to simply donate the rounded-up fractions of a penny and stop thinking.

Comment: @S.Lott: I agree. A worthwhile friendship cannot be destroyed for less than $0.01 `:)`

Comment: @e.James.  In this case. 10**-13 of a penny.

Comment: @S.Lott I think there are better things to spend your time on, than complaining about my question on an online forum.

Comment: @e.James thanks for taking the time to answer my question, regardless how silly it may have been.

Comment: @gumuz: No worries. I've written some financial software, so I know the pain of cents and rounding.

Comment: @gumuz: I think there are better things to spend your time on than asking questions like this in an online forum.  But that's just my opinion.  Yours may differ.

Comment: @gumuz: S.Lott does make a valid point, though. The best way to handle this is probably just to have *everyone* pay an extra $0.01 and then add the (minimal) extra to the tip.

Comment: @S.Lott well, it took me longer than you would've liked, but I learned something from. Also, your comment about floats vs decimals made sense and helped me understand the problem I (thought) had, time well spent :) thanks

Comment: @S.Lott Rounding UP is the standard solution? GAAP rules are at best ambiguous and at worst contradictory with respect to rounding. Ask
any *qualified* accountant and you will find the rules for rounding up, down or otherwise are
quite arbitrary. In most financial situations you are free to 
round using whatever method you want to as long
as the "materiality" of a statement is not affected.

Comment: @NealB: I guess my accountants have been too heavy-handed in stating their requirements.  I deleted the comment.

Comment: I disagre with the statement "When dealing with dollars and cents, there is no 100% clean way to handle the rounding."  Rounding isn't required at all for this solution.  See my answer for how/why. =)

Comment: @Sir Robert: Your solution involves no rounding because you are not splitting the bill. It is still a good solution (and I gave it an upvote), but it doesn't remove the need for a rounding when, for example, three people agree to evenly split a bill for $100. Of course, your solution would still work with a split bill, it would just have to divide and round off before filling in the "bill" amounts.

Comment: @e.James: Ohhhh I missed the part about splitting it evenly!  Woops!

Answer (score 9):

http://www.billmonk.com/

Amongst others.  The problem has already been solved.  Many times over.

---

> "Theoratically, the sum of the differences should be zero, right?"

Yes.  Since you've used `float`, however, you have representation issues when the number of people is not a power of two.

Never. Use. `float` For. Finance.

**Never**

Always. Use. `decimal` For. Finance.

**Always**

Comment: Thanks, I know, I'm amusing myself with this problem. It seems so easy, yet I can't do it... it frustrates me to no end :)

Comment: It's not an interesting problem.  It's add and subtract.

Comment: Way to (not) answer the question. So what if @gumuz wants to solve a problem that has been solved many times over?

Comment: @kaloyan: But @gumuz **did** totally solve it.  And used `float` and got confused by round-off errors.  @gumuz did not need a "solution".  @gumuz needed to stop using `float`.

Comment: "more like it"?  The answer hasn't changed.  What does your comment mean?

Comment: @S.Lott: +1 for the BillMonk link (pretty cool). -1 for being a grump. The problem was interesting enough to gumuz for him to take the time to write the question. It need not be dismissed as universally uninteresting. I bet he (and others) have learned something from the answers.

Comment: If I could give you two upvotes, I would - one for billmonk, one for your point about finance and floats.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a python guy, but I found it an interesting problem =)  Here's my solution.  Dev time ~45min.  I write clean perl... should be easy to port.

```
~/sandbox/$ ./bistro_math.pl 
Anna owes Bill 7.57
Anna owes Mike 2.16
John owes Mike 2.62

~/sandbox/$ cat bistro_math.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

### Dataset.
###    Bill total:  50.00
###    Paid total:  50.00
my @people = (
  { name => 'Bill', bill =>  5.43, paid => 13.00 },
  { name => 'Suzy', bill => 12.00, paid => 12.00 },
  { name => 'John', bill => 10.62, paid =>  8.00 },
  { name => 'Mike', bill =>  9.22, paid => 14.00 },
  { name => 'Anna', bill => 12.73, paid =>  3.00 },
);

### Calculate how much each person owes (or is owed: -/+)
calculate_balances(\@people);

### Tally it all up =)  This algorithm is designed to have bigger lenders
### paid back by the fewest number of people possible (they have the least
### hassle, since they were the most generous!).
sub calculate_balances {
  my $people = shift;

  ### Use two pools    
  my @debtors;
  my @lenders;

  foreach my $person (@$people) {
    ### Ignore people who paid exactly what they owed.
    $person->{owes} = $person->{bill} - $person->{paid};

    push @debtors, $person if ($person->{owes} > 0);
    push @lenders, $person if ($person->{owes} < 0);
  }

  LENDERS: foreach my $lender (@lenders) {
    next if ($lender->{owes} >= 0);

    DEBTORS: foreach my $debtor (@debtors) {
      next if ($debtor->{owes} <= 0);

      my $payment = ($lender->{owes} + $debtor->{owes} < 0) 
        ? abs $debtor->{owes} 
        : abs $lender->{owes};

      $lender->{owes} += $payment;
      $debtor->{owes} -= $payment;

      $debtor->{pays} = [] if (not exists $debtor->{pays});
      print "$debtor->{name} owes $lender->{name} $payment\n";

      next LENDERS if ($lender->{owes} >= 0);
    }
  }
}

exit;
~/sandbox/$
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the total everyone owed, and who was short. Take that total short that everyone was and divy it out to those who paid more, starting from the highest overpayer to lowest.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" you are seeing has to do with binary representation of floating-point numbers as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). At any rate, *7.1054273576010019e-015* is a tiny, tiny number, so if you round your results to the nearest cent, as you should, you wouldn't have any problems.